# Why is my form not being submitted when using render_esi Symfony 6

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, render, edge-side-includes

I am making a controller in symfony 6 for a search function and then calling it from my template using the "render_esi" method.
The template is rendering the form but when I click on the submit button, nothing happens other than the page being refreshed.
Here's the controller:

```
#[Route('/sav/search', name: 'app_sav_search', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(Request $request, ContratRepository $contratRepository): Response
    {
        $savSearch = new SAVSearch;
        $form = $this->createForm(SAVSearchType::class, $savSearch);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dd('Hi');
        }

        return $this->render('sav_search/_search-form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

I added the dd('hi') just to test if the form is being submitted, and it's not.

here's how im calling it on my template:

```
{{ render_esi(controller('App\\Controller\\SAVSearchController::index')) }}
```

I have had this exact problem in the same project somewhere else where I ended up just not using render_esi. But I need to use the search function in multiple page.

Here's also my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder'   => 'Recherchez ici',
                    'class'         => 'form-control search-input mr-sm-2',
                    'aria-label'    => 'Search',
                    'autocomplete'  =>  'off',
                    'spellcheck'    =>  'false',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary',
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
```

and lastly, the form template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'row col p-2'}}) }}
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.nom) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Am I missing something? or should I use another method? I would like any help

PS: the request is being sent, I can see that in my profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply this code to your controller.

```
    #[Route('/sav/search', name: 'app_sav_search', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function index(Request $request, ContratRepository $contratRepository): Response
    {
        $savSearch = new SAVSearch;
        $form = $this->createForm(SAVSearchType::class, $savSearch, 
         ['action' => $this->generateUrl('app_sav_search')]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dd('Hi');
        }

        return $this->render('sav_search/_search-form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: My Entity SAVSearch is made of only one variable. It's the variable for the filter: `nom`

I also tried the POST method and it doesn't work.
And in the profiler, there's no error. In fact, I can see the Request I made. I think the only problem is that it's not passing to the server side:

Comment: Please pass form action in this syntax `$form = $this->createForm(SAVSearchType::class, $savSearch);` because you are rendering this method in another page that's why your form is submitted with parent method instead of this `index` method

Comment: I see, so I need to handle the form request in the controller that's rendering the parent page instead of this controller?

Comment: @BadrAl-kebsi Please check my answer above the code snippet.

Comment: Please explain in your answer how this solves the question. Code-only answer are not good answers

Comment: @DarkBee You can check my above comment as an explanation

Comment: IMHO the comments are not quite clear